# How to handle com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException in android application when app is using FirebaseUI library?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using [firebaseUI android library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) in my android app. The login UI is launched on the app from MainActivity. The MainActivity onCreate() method will check if the login is already done or not. If not, it will show login screen which is launched from firebaseUI library.

Now if the user turned off internet and on the login screen and try to login with "Sign in with Google" button, the popup to select google accounts will appear. User can select one account and library shows progress bar. Since the internet is not there, the login fails, but there is no indication for the same on the login screen.

The logcat shows error as

```
E/CredentialSignInHandler: Unexpected exception when signing in with credential
                                                                                  com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

How can I handle this in my app and show the user some notification as to connect to internet?

Answer (score 0):

> My suggestion is to check your GoogleService-Info.plist for

- API_KEY is proper (without extra spaces)
- GOOGLE_APP_ID
- CLIENT_ID

I think this might help you

Answer (score 0):

you need to impliment onConnectionFailed ,see below code for reference.

- The  code for google sign in  is mostly boiler plate from

  - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
    and
  - https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java

    ```
      public void onSignInGooglePressed(View view) {
      Intent signInIntent =  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);

        ProgressDialog.show();
      }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
     /**
    * An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including   
    *  Sign-In) will not
    * be available.
    */
     ProgressDialog.dismiss();
     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    ```

Comment: if this help you give a thumbs up ,happy coding